# How to install private git repo with Yarn via access tokens without hardcoding in package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, npm, yarnpkg

I thought I could use `.npmrc` for v1 or `.yarnrc.yml` for v2/3/4 but in all cases Yarn doesn't even try to authenticate to Github

```
nodeLinker: node-modules

npmScopes:
  packagescope:
    npmAlwaysAuth: true
    npmAuthToken: my_personal_access_token
    npmRegistryServer: "https://npm.pkg.github.com"

yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.6.2.cjs
```

**It errors with:**

> error Command failed.
> Exit code: 128
> Command: git
> Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/user/some-dependency.git
> Directory: /home/me/Documents/projects/myapp
> Output:
> fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled

**When I go to github.com I find that the access token has never been used,** so apparently authentication is never even attempted.

How can I install the repo using access tokens without hardcoding them into the package.json? When I hardcoded them into package.json it worked fine, but that's terrible security practice, may break `git bisect` and has other downsides.

I can't simply use SSH because I need this to work with CI servers owned by third parties and I don't want to hand over unlimited access to all of our repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of GitHub fine-grained access tokens together with [EAS secret files](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/variables/#how-to-upload-a-secret-file-and-use-it-in-my-app-config).

**Note:** Must be configured using `--global` for EAS specifically because the preinstall step runs outside a git repo